# Apache Shiro 1.2.4 - 1.3.2

Tags: apache, shiro

Does anyone know where I can find the release notes from the version 1.2.4 until 1.3.2 for Apache Shiro.  I would like to know what is the difference is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded there "release notes".  It was on there news blog stating what was fixed and new features.  I anyone else is interested or could not find it.

https://shiro.apache.org/news.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Release notes are in the ASF JIRA instance:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO/fixforversion/12338327/

Comment: Thanx, I see it is only until version 2.0.0?

Comment: You should be able to navigate between versions from that screen.